# Pular uma linha no textView

Tags: android

Como pular uma linha em uma textView no Android Studio? Ou mesmo no que se refere a propria formatação do texto, deixar alguma parte em negrito por exemplo? existe algo integrado automático ou eu teria que mexe no .xml?

Comment: Olá. Seja bem-vindo ao SOPt. Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com pular linha? Que problema está enfrentando? Além disso, evite de fazer duas perguntas em uma só. Sua questão sobre o negrito seria melhor convertida em outra pergunta. Se ainda não o fez, faça o nosso [tour] para entender melhor como funciona o site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri como pular a linha. basta usar o "\n\n"

Comment: Mas você deve usar um só \n. Exemplo: "blá blá blá \n"

Answer (score 1):

Você usa \n para a quantidade de linhas que deseja pular, tipo, se quiser pular uma linha: \n, duas linhas: \n\n, três linhas: \n\n\n  e assim sucessivamente !

quanto ao Negrito: eu uso no textstyle: bold

EX.:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Teste"/>
```